# Hide column in Pivot Table in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I want to hide a column pivot table. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "conditional" expression. you have it both in expression and in dimension,
BUT - when you use pivot table I don't recommend using this on a dimension because it can rearrange your horizontal/vertical field settings in the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: Thing to remember is that those conditions turn on and off the calculation of the column as well. So you couldn't have Column(1)/Column(2) and have column 2 conditioned away as you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way that you do with a straight table (on the Presentation tab), but you can make individual dimensions or expressions conditionally enabled or disabled.